# Why does my object show again after it is faded out with css?

Tags: jquery, css

I have some divs showing and I would like to fade them out using css.

My logic is to add the css class which points to my animation declaration onto the objects when I want this to happen, e.g.

Css:

```
.fadeout { -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
```

Jquery:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#something').addClass('fadeout')
});
```

The fadeout works fine. But then once it is finished, it shows my faded object again.

What is the logic I am missing here? It doesn't keep the opacity 0 once it has finished animating but reverts to the original state.

**Note:**
The solution needs to be animating via css - I'm aware of jquery's fadeout functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.fadeout {-webkit-animation:fadeout 1s;animation:fadeout 1s;opacity:0;}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes fadeout { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6a4RQ/1)

Comment: Ahh. Adding the opacity 0 to the fadeout class did the trick. I would have thought this would just make the object immediately hidden, but it applies the opacity after the fadeout animation completes. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove element:

```
$("#something").fadeOut(300, function(){ 
    $(this).remove();
});
```

So it won't be shown again.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the solution needs to be in CSS - not using jquery's fadeout functions.

Answer (score 1):

In light of that this needs to be done with CSS, use this:

```
.fadeout { 
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
     opacity: 0;
}
```

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/X64B3/